# Repair Repository after repeated pull/merge requests

Tags: git, github, merge, pull

I am a git noob ...
I want to revert back to 92e4013f73 and get rid of all the mistakes I made by doing multiple git pulls.

```
*   b9a908ea64 (origin/this_variable) Merge branch 'foo-bar:dev' into this_variable
|\
* \   1a3611f735 Merge branch 'foo-bar:dev' into this_variable
|\ \
* \ \   e8044a33fa Merge branch 'foo-bar:dev' into this_variable
|\ \ \
* \ \ \   6e9fe81632 Merge branch 'foo-bar:dev' into this_variable
|\ \ \ \
* \ \ \ \   e656766969 Merge branch 'foo-bar:dev' into this_variable
|\ \ \ \ \
* | | | | | d36c348ac4 (HEAD -> dev) Add this variable
| | | | | | *   3f0736c13b (origin/entity_id_template) Merge branch 'foo-bar:dev' into entity_id_template
| | | | | | |\
| | | | | | |/
| | | | | |/|
| | | | | * | 92e4013f73 (origin/save_persistent_states, origin/dev, origin/HEAD) Fix siren turn on parameter filtering (#52947)
| | | | | * | 6723942bf8 [ci skip] Translation update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any work in progress, you can simply reset `this_variable` branch to dev, and then retry your work/merges from there.
Again, this assumes:

- you don't have files currently being modified (or their local modification would be lost)
- you are the only one working on `this_variable` (allowing you to force push it back to origin)

```sh
cd /path/to/repo
git switch this_variable
git reset --hard dev
git push --force
```